# Toolbar not visible AppCompat v7 level 22

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I am using Toolbar like this in activity

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" >
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

here is my style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

**Problem**

If I use windowNoTitle "TRUE" there is not toolbar in main activity. If I use windowNoTitle "FALSE" it throws exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AppCompat does not support the current theme features
```

What is wrong I am doing?

Comment: You're confusing ActionBar and Toolbar. Also why would you add the toolbar and then use NoActionBar in your theme? What's the point of this? Maybe if you explain what you're trying to achieve you can get some concrete help.

Comment: I want to use Toolbar hence added it to Activity layout. To use Toolbar I need to disable ActionBar that is what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

First off, good on you for using the latest design that has a **ToolBar** and not an **ActionBar** (deprecated in material design). Check out this guide: 
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-App-ToolBar

You're nearly there; to stop the exception from occuring, remove `<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>` from your XML. The theme already has no actionbar, so you're essentially trying to say "no actionbar" twice, which Android doesn't like and considers illegal.

Follow the rest of the guide to get your toolbar displayed. You're probably just missing this stuff in your activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Find the toolbar view inside the activity layout
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        // Sets the Toolbar to act as the ActionBar for this Activity window.
        // Make sure the toolbar exists in the activity and is not null
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    // Menu icons are inflated just as they were with actionbar
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Be especially mindful of `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`, which tells the framework to treat the `toolbar` as the Actionbar. Yay Material Design!

Comment: removed windowActionBar thing made "windowNoTitle" true. But no toolbar on top.

Comment: It seems something at my end something related to Fragment transaction. Will update you.

Answer (score 0):

1. styles.xml file in values

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

2. styles.xml file in values-v21

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```

3. in manifest file

android:theme="@style/AppTheme"